# How can I avoid re-renderging of child component using React.memo?

Tags: react-hooks

React.memo is not working as I expect.

Every time, I click the 'Button', the 'Oh No..' message is displayed.

I think displaying 'Oh No..' message means re-rendering of child component.

How do I modify my code to prevent re-rendering of child component caused by parent rendering?

```
import React from 'react';

function Test() {
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
  
  const Box = () => {
    React.useEffect(() => console.info('Oh No..'), []);
    return (<div>Box</div>)
  };
  const MemoBox = React.memo(Box);

  return (
    <div>
      <MemoBox/>
      <button onClick={()=>setPage(page+1)}>Button</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Test;
```

[test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSNvV.png)

I thought when I use React.memo, I can avoid re-rendering caused by parent re-redering.
I expected 'Oh No..' message is displayed once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React.memo is not intended to be used as a "hook" inside of another component. Currently every time Test is rerendered - Box function is recreated and MemoBox variable is reasigned on each render. So every render - it is a "new" thing.

You can use React.useMemo or React.useCallback if you want to keep the declaration of Box and MemoBox inside Test component.

```js
function Test() {
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);

  const Box = () => {
    React.useEffect(() => console.info("Oh No.."), []);
    return <div>Box</div>;
  };

  // or or
  const MemoBox2 = React.useMemo(() => Box, []);
  const MemoBox = React.useCallback(Box, []);

  useEffect(() => console.log(page), [page]);

  return (
    <div>
      <MemoBox />
      <button onClick={() => setPage(page + 1)}>Button</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you want to use React.memo - then you need to move Box declaration and React.memo outside:

```js
function Test() {
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);

  useEffect(() => console.log(page), [page]);

  return (
    <div>
      <MemoBox />
      <button onClick={() => setPage(page + 1)}>Button</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const Box = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => console.info("Oh No.."), []);
  return <div>Box</div>;
};

const MemoBox = React.memo(Box);
```